# Estoy desarrollando un crud, al momento de probarlo el crud me manda un error

Tags: php, mysql

El error sucede en cuanto voy a actualizar para agregar datos a la tabla, el error es el siguiente

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'IDENTIFICACION' in 'field list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud compras\Ajustes.php:172 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\crud compras\Ajustes.php(172): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud compras\Ajustes.php on line 172

Y la linea 172 es la siguiente

```html
$resultado->execute(array(":usu"=>$usuario, ":iden"=>$identificacion, ":com"=>$compra, ":des"=>$destino, ":fec"=>$fecha));
```

Comment: puedes indicar que es `$resultado`, donde lo obtienes y tambien que contiene `$identificacion` ? el metodo `execute` de ese objeto esta requiriendo un campo `identificacion`...

Comment: Si agregas todo el codigo seria bastante mejor, por que en el error queda claro que estas apuntando a una columna llamada `IDENTIFICACION` la cual no existe en el schema de la tabla.

Comment: Creo que seria útil que agregaras un poco más de código para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, el error ya fue solucionado, pues en la base de datos la columna tenia mal escrita la palabra identificación